# Second and third person at beginning of Mishpatim

Tags: grammar-dikduk, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim

The start of *Mishpatim* (Exodus 21:2-6) discusses the Hebrew slave. It starts with "*Ki **sikneh** eved ivri*" - "When **you** will buy a Hebrew slave", referring to the master in the second person. The remainder of passage uses the the third person for the master, as in "*Im **adonav** yiten lo isha*" - "If **his master** will give him a wife". Why the change?

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17010/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sifrei** [says](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hwmeyp#view=1up;seq=161) in Deuteronomy Re'eh:

> מנין כשאתה קונה לא תהא קונה אלא עבד עברי שנאמר כי תקנה עבד עברי
>
> <sup>*From where [do we know] when you buy [a slave] you should only buy a Hebrew slave? As it says: 'When you shall buy a Hebrew slave.*</sup>

**Ohr Hachaim** [explains very similarly](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38298&st=&pgnum=75&hilite=) in Exodus on our verse (The Birchas Shimon, who comments on the Ohr Hachaim, points this out, citing the Sifrei):

> <sup>*Perhaps that it means to say that if it will be before him to buy a Canaanite slave and a Hebrew slave, he should prioritize the Hebrew, and that is the measure of the verse, when **you will** want to buy a slave, prioritize buying a Hebrew, and don't say 'I will buy a slave that I will work with him forever, and I will not buy a slave that after six years I will send him off'...*</sup>

It seems like the direct language is being expounded upon, as opposed to a more incidental *'If a man shall buy a Hebrew slave...'*

This interpretation is further reinforced, in my opinion by the [cantillation marks](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/hr/tables.htm#dis21). Over the word, תקנה‏, *you shall acquire*, we find a Pashta, a distinctive mark of the second degree, meaning that it enforces a moderate pause in the verse, making it read like so (number of commas indicate strength of pause):

> ,,,,כי תקנה,, עבד עברי,,, שש שנים,,, יעבד,,,, ובשביעית,,, יצא לחפשי,,, חנם‏
>
> <sup>*When you shall acquire **,,** a Hebrew servant **,,,** six years **,,,** he shall serve **,,,,** and on the seventh **,,,** he shall go free **,,,** free of charge **,,,,***</sup>

That pause could cause the verse to be read:

> <sup>*When you shall acquire [a slave, it should be] a Hebrew slave*</sup>