# Why does the language in a typical bracha (blessing) change from an individual request to mentioning a group?

Tags: blessing, hebrew

A typical bracha starts (or ends)  ברוך אתה ה hich seems to be an individual praise, as you are individually acknowledging that He is **your** (personal) G-d (As I understand, אדוני means **my** Lord). Then, after that, we say אלוקינו meaning **our** G-d.

Why is there a change in language from addressing G-d individually to mentioning G-d in a group (plural) format?

Comment: Same by Shema Yisrael

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17010/759

Comment: I don't see anything about being your personal G-d. You are merely pronouncing Hashem's name.

Comment: @HaLeiVi has a good point - the "proper" method would have us pronouncing YHVH rather than the "personal" stand-in. Neither here nor the Shema are really a question along those lines. What IS interesting is why they chose that SPECIFIC kinui to use instead of YHVH, rather than something like "HaMakom."

Comment: The ibn Ezra, in Shemos I think, explains that a name doesn't have a suffix. You don't say ראובנים. Since this is a name of Hashem, personal connotation doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is my own thoughts, although I would not be surprised if this is mentioned elsewhere.

When we make a Bracha we are building up. First we mention Hashem, then we say אלוקינו - which indicates the God of the Jews, then we say Melech Haolam - which indicates the king of the entire world.

Comment: But why do we do that? I think that's the question.

Comment: If it would be going in that order it would be Malkeinu and then Elokim. A god is more than a king.