# What's the difference between "Hinchilanu" and "Hinchaltanu"?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, kiddush

The Kiddush for Friday night contains two verbs, Hinchilanu and Hinchaltanu, that seem to be on one Hebrew root and share the translation "has given us as a heritage."

[image]

I guess that there must be some gramatical explanation for the slight change in the spelling and pronunciation. But I cannot figure out what that explanation would be.

Comment: Of interest https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68946/second-and-third-person-in-birchat-kohanim http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17010/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96292/%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%9b%d7%95%d7%aa-switch-between-2nd-and-3rd-person/96293#96293

Answer (score 6, accepted):

הנחילנו is in the third person: He has given us as a heritage.

הנחלתנו is in the second person: You have given us as a heritage.

Comment: Same as קדשו vs קדשך

Comment: Notice that Brachos start addressing Hashem directly, 2nd person (or *nochach*) and then switch to 3rd person (*nistar*). "Bless **You**, who sanctified us in **His** ... a longer bracha like this actually goes: 2nd person, 3rd person, 2nd person again.