# Why on Kiddush on Friday night do we switch from third person to second person?

Tags: kiddush

Does anyone know of a source explaining why on קידוש on Friday night we switch from הנחילנו ("He gave us as an inheritance") to הנחלתנו ("You gave us as an inheritance")? I thought it was a רשב"א in a תשובה but don't know how to search for it.
Thanks so much!

Comment: That Rashba is brought in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96293).

Comment: See also related questions [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128365), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68946), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17010).

Comment: @Fred Yeah, this happens a lot in brachos.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Noach and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!